# apply single tick mark before and after concatenated values in single cell

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I would like to combine single tick marks before and after concatenated values in excel.  Ultimately i need this to be passed into a SQL query

```
EX: 

Before-->pig, dog, bird, cat   cell A1

After-->'pig','dog','bird','cat'    cell A2 

Used For:

WHERE
a.Type IN ('pig','dog','bird','cat')
```

Comment: `split` then `for each e in arr | "'" & e & "'"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the formula:

```
="'" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","','") & "'"
```

[image]

Comment: you are awesome, i love stackoverflow